# PhoneGap/Cordova onClick region on physical iOS device

Tags: cordova

I've recently started helping someone out with a mobile application built on PhoneGap (v2.2.0).  We're currently focusing on iOS.

One of the problems they're having is that sometimes the "buttons" aren't clickable over the entire viewable region making it frustrating for the user.

- These buttons are basically just `divs` with `onClick` events on them.
- I've found that the entire region of the `div` fires the `onClick` event if I run the app in the browser or in the iOS 6.1 emulator through Xcode.  The problem only exists once I load the app onto a physical device.
- There seems to be a 15px wide "dead" area where the event doesn't fire.  Sometimes this is the entire right side (the right-most 15 px or so) of the div, but sometimes it's the top 15 px or so.
- I've distilled the app to the barebones to eliminate any problems that could be cause by other JS libraries or CSS sheets.  The entire example app is the following index.html.  In this example, the top 100x15px of the 100x100px div doesn't fire events.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var platform = '';
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

        if (userAgent.indexOf('android') > 0) {
            platform = 'android';
        }

        else if (userAgent.indexOf('blackberry') > 0 || userAgent.indexOf('BB10') > 0) {
            platform = 'blackberry';
        }

        else if (userAgent.indexOf('iphone') > 0 || userAgent.indexOf('ipad') > 0 || userAgent.indexOf('ipod') > 0) {
            platform = 'ios';
        }

        // Using document.write here because head.appendChild(script) takes too long in Android 4.0+
        if (platform) {
            document.write('<script charset="utf-8" src="jscripts\/cordova\/cordova-2.2.0-' + platform + '.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working");

            document.getElementById("btnButton").addEventListener("click", fooBar, false);
        }

        function fooBar() {
            document.getElementById("btnButton").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="btnButton" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color: red; color:white;" onclick="navigator.notification.alert('Sorry, incorrect');"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

If anyone out there can give me any pointers, it could keep me from pulling out what's left of my hair.  I've spent the last day and a half going through this, removing stuff, and Googling and I'm sort of out ideas.

Comment: Update:  I've done some more testing.  It's not just that the section isn't registering the screen taps, it's that it's registering them in a different position.  If I stack two divs similar to the code above on top of each other, the top ~15px of the bottom box register as clicks on the top box.

Comment: Update2: I captured the touchstart event in the app and the vertical position is actually coming up differently in the emulator and on the device.  pageY = 0 doesn't come up until 0.5cm down the screen on the device.  It's right at the top of the screen in the emulator.

Comment: Very strange. I tried it on my iPad but the region registers fine for me. Have you tried using touchstart or touchend events instead of click? Touchstart is a bit more responsive/immediate in some cases - likely not related to this issue you're seeing but might shed some light on something though?